# What are the difference between tanks from different countries?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I want to find out what the difference between defensive and offensive "specializations" of tanks in the various trees are. Something like (and this is what I heard a friend mention) "German tanks are heavier armored and have precise guns, French are just bulky and Russians have fast tanks).

Basically, where do I go if I want a hard-hitting Destroyer, an Arty that aims the fastest, or the fastest light tank (among other questions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tankopedia](http://worldoftanks.com/encyclopedia/vehicles/) is a great place to browse through the available tanks.

## SPGs

1. German

   - High damage/penetration
   - Long range
   - Small cone of fire
2. Russian

   - Lowest damage/penetration
   - Fastest reload
   - Shortest range
   - Largest cone of fire
   - Highest trajectory (can shoot targets behind cover easier)
3. American

   - Good damage
   - Great accuracy
   - Long range
   - High mobility
4. French

   - Good damage
   - Decent accuracy
   - Slowest reload
   - High Mobility
   - Long range

Comment: So, anything else about what the tanks aren't good at? I mean, Germans have highest damage, but... say, low aiming time or accuracy? Also, linking me to a page that lists all the data on tanks isn't necessary, as the data is just the same in the game, and I think I've already checked it.

Comment: What are you looking for specifically? I could run down the pros and cons of each nation's destroyers, SPGs, and light tanks. If you are looking for a high level overview, traits like "fastest aim" may not be so useful. It may also depend on what tier you are talking about.

Comment: So you mean that the countries don't have that specific differences? Ok, then why would I go with (as an example:) a French SPG over a German, Russian, French, British or USA one? Also, second post: http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/240255-whats-the-difference-between-the-tanks-by-countries/

Comment: The countries have slight differences, but it really comes down to your play style and which tanks you discover you like as you play the game. I will edit my answer to explain SPG differences if that's what you are looking for. I can also edit the question to match the response. Just let me know. Are you thinking in general or a specific tier?

Comment: Yes, in general please.

Comment: hmmm are you sure you're not confusing russian SPGs with the british ones?

Answer (score 1):

Difference between tanks from different countries is crew size and/or specialization (for example, soviet tanks early loss radioman, and crew size reduced from 5 to 4 men) and some equipment (for example, american tanks have Vertical Stabilizer from 6th tier when others from 7-8th tiers).

More specific parameters such armor, rate of fire, mobility depend on the specific tank.

- German Panther have a great penetration but german VK 30.02(D) on
  same tier have better mobility and diesel engine with rear transmission but 48mm less
  penetration.
- French ARL 44 have a good armor and slow when AMX 50/100 poorly armored but have an incredible firepower and mobility.
- Soviet IS-4 have thick rear and side armor and high penetration with moderate damage when IS-7 have poorly armored rear, high damage and moderate penetration.

Comparison of nations is meaningless. You need to compare specific tanks.

Answer (score 0):

**HARD HITTING TANK DESTROYERS**

---

Tier 8

- US T28 / T28 Prototype
- German Ferdinand / JPanther 2 / Rhm Borsig
- Russians ISU-152
- British  Charioteer (high dpm)

Tier 9

- US T95 / T30
- German Jagtiger / Wt Pz IV (use the big gun)
- Russians Obj 704
- British Conway

Tier 10

- US T110E3 / T110E4
- German Jagpanzer E100
- Russian Obj 263 / Obj 268
- British FV4005 stage2 / FV215b (183)

*side note

Tanks like the T110E4 or T30 shouldn't be played like a TD, it is sort of a TD/HT hybrid. Holding flanks/ pushing with HTs can work wonders. If mm hates you, you might want to consider taking up the HT role for your team and support their advance or hold flanks with them.

**ARTILLERY**

---

(BIG SPLASHES)
Tier 8

- US M40/M43
- German Gw Tiger P
- Russian Su-14-2

Tier 9

- US M53/M55

Tier 10

- US T92
- Britain Conqueror GC

(OTHER TRAITS)
 - french line (high mobility, low dmg per shot, okayish accuracy)

**LIGHT TANKS**

---

COMPETITIVE (Strongholds/Clanwars)

Tier 6

- US T37
- French AMX 12t (situational, not all the time)

Tier 8
 - Russian T54 Lightweight (brawling monster)
 - German RU 251 (dpm at its best, fastest of all)
 - Chinese WZ-132 (shadows the russian lightweight) 
 - French AMX 13-90

NORMAL RANDOM GAME CHOICE

Tier 5

- French ELC AMX
- US Chaffee (dodgy to play)
- German Leopard

Tier 6

- view top list

Tier 7

- US M41 bulldog (10 shot autoloader) / T71 (6 shot autoloader)
- German SP1C (3 shot 90mm autoloader)

Tier 8
 - US T49 (152mm gun launcher to delete enemies, especially paper ones)

---

---

That about sums up all the answers to your questions

Happy Tanking ;)